# Why is Scorpius so interested in Stykera?

Tags: farscape

Scorpius was clearly interested in Stark, that's why he kept him... and in the 3 part episode with the shadow depository and Jothee Scorpius asked if there were any Stykera among the 10000 Banik slaves he had bought, he also stated that he was looking for a replacement.

And another odd thing from that particular episode (part 2, I think): Scorpius contacted Moya to speak with Crichton or Ka D'Argo but Zaan answered to tell him that the two weren't available and then Stark appeared out of nowhere yelling at Scorpy. When he took off his mask Scorpy ended the transmission. What's up with that?! Did Stark's sparkly nature had any effect on Scorpius?

Comment: I think these would do well as separate questions, since the only relationship between them is that Stark and Scorpius are involved

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can remember, it's not Stykera specifically that Scorpius was interested in, and the [Farscape wikia](http://farscape.wikia.com/wiki/Aurora_Chair) tends to agree:

> Scorpius had put Stark through over 100 sessions in the chair in hopes
>   of learning about the Scarran's crystherium flowers before John
>   Crichton arrived on the base.

Stark was once a prisoner/slave on Katratzi, the hidden Scarran base.